# Hibernate prepareConnection/preparedStatement issues

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

Within our project, we have updated Spring to `4.3.14.RELEASE` and Hibernate to `4.3.11.Final` and since we have started seeing two warnings:

1. > WARN JDBC Connection to reset not identical to originally prepared Connection - please make sure to use connection release mode ON_CLOSE (the default) and to run against Hibernate 4.2+ (or switch HibernateJpaDialect's prepareConnection flag to false

   - The cure is to switch the release mode to `ON_CLOSE`, which we don't want – when our app is under heavy load, at some point it stops releasing the connections and the application gets stuck. This works correctly with release mode AFTER_TRANSACTION.
   - The message doesn't say what happens if this error is ignored. Googling doesn't show anything definitive
   - What happens if we switch the `prepareConnection` flag to `false`? I tried to find such flag in Hibernate configuration but couldn't find it.
2. > GooGooStatementCache:441 - Multiply prepared statement!

   - Is this warning related to the previous one? Is it something we should worry?

EDIT: I updated Hibernate to `5.2.13.Final`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the explanation of multiply prepared statements (from the [GooGooStatementCache source](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/master/src/java/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/stmt/GooGooStatementCache.java#L461-L465)):

> The same statement has already been prepared by this Connection, 
>   and that other instance has not yet been closed, so the statement pool
>   has to prepare a second PreparedStatement object rather than reusing
>   the previously-cached Statement. The new Statement will be cached, in case 
>   you frequently need multiple copies of this Statement.

In English, what this means is the same `PreparedStatement` was checked out from a `Connection` before the same `PreparedStatement` from the same `Connection` was checked in. This is unusual. Only one client and `Thread` typically interacts with a `Connection` at a time, and usually one would reuse the same `PreparedStatement` (resetting its parameters) if it is required multiple times. Probably the most likely reason this happens is because the application does not `close()` the `PreparedStatement`s that it opens, relying upon c3p0 to clean them up on `Connection` checkin.

In any case, it's not a correctness problem, c3p0 will handle the case just fine. But it probably reflects code that could be cleaned up a bit (either by `close()-ing` `PreparedStatement`s promptly after use or reusing them) to be more efficient in memory and resource use. If you are using the current version (0.9.5.2), c3p0 should have shown you the text of the problematic `PreparedStatement`.

---

I don't know why you are seeing the Spring/Hibernate warning. c3p0 checked out `Connection`s are proxies, but their identities do not change within their client-visible lifecycles. Looking a bit at the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/73cf07e9a4f1000087118c24ef5d56f621f41160/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaDialect.java), there's some reflection and indirection in getting the `Connection` associated with a `Session`, which then becomes compared to the one that was checked out. Perhaps something causes the `Session` to refresh its associated `Connection` even while the `Connection` and `Session` are in use? I wish I could be of more help, but I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive response. As I am just using `@Transactional` annotation, I don't really open, nor close connections, so it is hard to say, how could it lead to these. I can see the text of the PreparedStatement, but as this is an SQL for fetching an entity, this can be anywhere in the project. I guess stack trace would be much more helpful. Anyway, you are jsut answering the second part of question, but the first is the one which is more important.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue by using Tomcat JDBC Pool.

The problem comes in spring because they do a equality check at line 351
[HibernateJpaDialect](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/73cf07e9a4f1000087118c24ef5d56f621f41160/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaDialect.java)

The comparison is done on a Connection proxied by the Connection Pool (either Tomcat Pool or c3p0 in your case).

If you setup ON_CLOSE (legacy behavior in hibernate) the connection is only closed when the session is reset/closed which doesn't raise any problem but could change the performance especially if the client keeps Hibernate sessions open for a while.

If you setup (default) AFTER_TRANSACTION the connection is released after the transaction complete and before the session close. line 301 [JdbcCoordinatorImpl](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/internal/JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java)

Normally, this method resetSessionState() checks not to close a connection twice
[line 349](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/73cf07e9a4f1000087118c24ef5d56f621f41160/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaDialect.java) `if (this.preparedCon != null && this.session.isConnected())`

The problem comes because the connection (proxied by the connection pool) changed during the first release (after transaction) and the equality is not met what causes the warn message.
This warning message is a false positive

Comment: This explaines the behavior we experienced perfectly. On load hikari would keep the connections active for far to long until we run out of available connections. Which throws 'JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection'. To help this we switched to AFTER_TRANSACTION which seems to resolve the first issue but also raises the 'JDBC Connection to reset...' warning. For now we suppress logs from the HibernateJpaDialect class, but is there an official fix for it?

Answer (score 2):

you could try with the property hibernate.connection.handling_mode

```
hibernate.connection.handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_HOLD
```

If you are using JTA

```
hibernate.connection.handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION
```

or

```
hibernate.connection.handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_STATEMENT
```

see this [springframework javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.html) section **setPrepareConnection**

Comment: Yes, that was it the difference between JPA and JTA

Answer (score 1):

Disable `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` by following Settings:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    hibernate:
      connection:
        release_mode: on_close # default mode, you can remove this line
```

Comment: I think the `spring.jpa.open-in-view` configuration option is Spring Boot specific.